# Scheme #!unspecific object appearing after sorting

Tags: sorting, functional-programming, scheme

I am working with a scheme program and have encountered an issue when trying to utilize my sort function. I have written it to utilize 2 other helper functions, which I have tested and can confirm work as intended, but when sorting, I receive the correct list with an #!unspecific object appended to it. I am not sure how this object was created or how to avoid this side effect.

The code for the functions is as follows:

```
(define sort
    (lambda (roster)
        (if (not (null? roster))
            (cons (smallest roster (car roster)) (sort (remove roster     (smallest roster (car roster)))))
        )
    )
)

(define smallest
    (lambda (roster item)
        (cond 
            ((null? roster) item)
            ((< (string->number (car (car roster))) (string->number (car item))) (smallest (cdr roster) (car roster)))
            (else (smallest (cdr roster) item))
        )
    )
)

(define remove
    (lambda (roster record)
        (cond 
            ((null? roster) '())
            ((equal? (car roster) record) (cdr roster))
            (else (cons (car roster) (remove (cdr roster) record)))
        )
    )
```

)

When I call the sort function with a test roster, I get the following result:

`(("1" "Anon" "89") ("2" "Student" "90") ("3" "Test" "78") . #!unspecific)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your **if**, there's a *then* part, but no *else* part, so the value that's returned when **roster** is  null is unspecified:

```
(if (not (null? roster))
    (cons (smallest roster (car roster))
          (sort (remove roster (smallest roster (car roster)))))
    ;; nothing here
    )
```

To confirm, try something like

```
(cons 1 (if #t 'then))
```

and you should see something like

```
(1 . #!unspecific)
```

What *should* **sort** return when **roster** is null?  I'd guess the empty list.  For style, I'd probably invert the condition to have something like:

```
(if (null? roster)
    roster            ; or '()
    (cons ...))
```

Comment: Thanks, inverted the condition like you said and added an else clause returning an empty list. Works great now!