# Scheme #!unspecific on display

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to figure out why I got #!unspecific on output.
I checked other post forum about it but still couldn't figure out what is causing it.

```
TEST 12: ----- process-square       side=3.16228
Side = 3.16228
Perimeter = 12.64911
Area = 10.
#!unspecific
```

This is my code

```
;Calculate Distance 
(define (get-dist-sq x1 y1 x2 y2) 
        (+ (expt (- x2 x1) 2) 
                (expt (- y2 y1) 2))
)

;Calculates the distance between two points
(define (dist-square p1 p2)
    (get-dist-sq (get-x p1) (get-y p1) (get-x p2) (get-y p2))
)

;Check if it is a square
(define (is-square p1 p2 p3 p4)
    (let ((d2 (dist-square p1 p2)) (d3 (dist-square p1 p3)) (d4 (dist-square p1 p4)))
        (cond 
        ((or (equal? d2 0) (equal? d3 0) (equal? d4 0)) #f)
        ((and (equal? d2 d3) (equal? (* 2 d2) d4) (equal? (* 2 (dist-square p2 p4)) (dist-square p2 p3))) #t)
        ((and (equal? d3 d4) (equal? (* 2 d3) d2) (equal? (* 2 (dist-square p3 p2)) (dist-square p3 p4))) #t)
        ((and (equal? d2 d4) (equal? (* 2 d2) d3) (equal? (* 2 (dist-square p2 p3)) (dist-square p2 p4))) #t)
        (else #f))
    )
)

;Calculate square side length
(define (sq-side-length p1 p2)
    (distance p1 p2)
)

;Calculate square area,  A= side^2
(define (square-area p1 p2 p3 p4)
    (expt (sq-side-length p1 p2) 2)
)

;Calculate square perimeter,   P= side * 4
(define (square-perimeter p1 p2 p3 p4)
    (* (sq-side-length p1 p2) 4)
)

;Display square calculations
(define (display-square p1 p2 p3 p4)
    (display "Side = ")
    (display (round-five-decimal (sq-side-length p1 p2)))
    (newline)

    (display "Perimeter = ")
    (display (round-five-decimal (square-perimeter p1 p2 p3 p4)))
    (newline)

    (display "Area = ")
    (display (round (square-area p1 p2 p3 p4)))
    (newline)
)

;Process square and display it
(define (process-square p1 p2 p3 p4)
    (if (equal? #t (is-square p1 p2 p3 p4))
        (display-square p1 p2 p3 p4)
        (display "Error: The 4 points does not form a square"))
)
```

This is the test

```
(display "TEST 12: ----- process-square     side=3.16228")
(newline)
(display (process-square (make-point 3 1) (make-point 2 4) (make-point 5 5) (make-point 6 2)))
(newline)
```

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509192/scheme-unspecific-object-appearing-after-sorting -- I'd check the `if` and `cond` forms

Answer (score 2):

Your code prints something and returns a value.

The returned value is the same as the returned value of `newline` (at the end of the `test`), which is undefined by definition.  For this undefined value your scheme implementation uses the symbol `#!unspecific`

Call your scheme interpreter with some `--silent` option to get rid of the returned value.

I cannot reproduce your code as I do not know what metaobject protocol are you using -- but this is not an important detail for your question.